# Android Facebook login with aws cognito wont hold login session?

Tags: java, android, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When I close my application after successfully logging into facebook, sometimes it signs me back into facebook after opening it back up and sometimes it doesn't? It is very inconsistent with logging back into the signed in user.

For Example: 
- I login successfully and close the app without logging out.
- I open app back up but it doesn't remember my session so i am not signed in. I close the app without signing in.
- I open the app again and it magically remembers my session from before.

It does this on and off very inconsistently and i have no idea why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

What i needed to do was update all the imported dependencies and add

initializeFacebookSdk();

before setting the content view in onCreate in the SplashActivity created by the aws mobile app demo.

No more problems now.

Comment: can u provide the link to see the content of sample app

Comment: You need to login to aws and download it through their dashboard. There is no simple link as there is some customization you need to do before they give you the source code

Answer (score 0):

Cognito android SDK does not manage the tokens from the Facebook (or any other IdP). But it manages the aws credentials and automatically refreshes it when they expire. Credentials and identity id is cached on the device. As long as the credentials are valid (1 hour), Cognito does not need the Token from facebook, but when the credentials are expired, it needs the valid token from Facebook. This might be the reason you are seeing the behavior related to session. To fix this problem, one approach will be to cache the Facebook token locally and make sure to populate it in logins map of CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider in the android activities which gets called when the app resumes. Additionally you will need to ensure that you refresh the Facebook token when it expires.

Comment: I know this but it doesn't explain why it is sporadic?